# Intercept Drag&Drop event on a calendar

Tags: event, calendar

Is it possible to intercept the Drag&Drop event called when I drag&drop an event/task on a calendar ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot for context?

Comment: The context is : I have a task for a meeting on my 7-days calendar. For example my task is on Friday between 1-5PM and I want to drag and drop it between 3-7PM. I want to intercept the drag&drop event. Is it possible and where can I find the code ?

Comment: Is there something you don't understand ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the file called after the drop event : /cal/weekly.apexp

And in the post request there are two parameters : dragSource et dropTarget.

Comment: No one have any ideas ?